# How to draw line from point to point on a 4 x 4 grid with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: 3 x 3 grid / complete compilable code]

How do I draw a straight line from the bottom left corner to the top right corner in tikz?

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={shape=circle,fill=black,scale=0.3}}
\tikzset{withtext/.style={fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
            % setup the nodes
            \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
            \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
            {
            \ifnum\x=4
                \ifnum\y=4
                    \node (\x-\y) at (\x,\y){X};
                \else
                    \node[mystyle] (\x-\y) at (\x,\y){};
                \fi
            \else
                \node[mystyle] (\x-\y) at (\x,\y){};
            \fi}
             \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{minipage}
       \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: what is your complete compilable code? Please can you put in?

Comment: `\draw (0-0)-- (3-3);`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

You only need to define node name in lower left corner, which is at `\x=0` and `\y=0` (since `\foreach` loops start at this corner): `(0-0)` and at top right corner, which is at  `\x=3` and `\y=3`  (since `\foreach` loops stop at this corner):   `(3-3)` and than drive arrow:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={shape=circle,fill=black,scale=0.3}}
\tikzset{withtext/.style={fill=white}}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.5]
% setup the nodes
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
\foreach \y in {0,...,3}
{
    \node[mystyle] (\x-\y) at (\x,\y) {};
}
\draw[red,-Straight Barb, semithick]
    (0-0) -- (3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%       \end{minipage}
%       \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- I took a liberty and significantly simplifying your code for loops.
- To see order of draving nodes, for test write nodes as

```
\node[mystyle,label={\tiny x,y=\x,\y}] (\x-\y) at (\x,\y){};
```

and you will see

[image]